# How do I create a "counting" filter?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of pairs and I need a filter that retains only elements where the first member of the pair occurred at least twice:

```
someFilter :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
someFilter   [("a",1),("a",2),("b",1)]
  `shouldBe` [("a",1),("a",2)]         -- "a" occurs in two pairs, retain both

someFilter   [("a",1),("a",2),("b",1),("b",2)]
  `shouldBe` [("a",1),("a",2),("b",1),("b",2)] -- "a" and "b" occur twice

someFilter   [("a",1),("b",2),("c",1),("d",2)]
  `shouldBe` [] -- no string occurs twice
```

I'm not really sure how one would implement such a filter. The usual `filter` works only element-wise. How would one write `someFilter`?

Comment: What if `list1 = [("a",1),("a",2),("b",1),("b",2)]`?

Comment: Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Explicit answer: it's not even a question. And we don't know where you're stuck.

Comment: @thefourtheye: [("a",1),("a",2),("b",1),("b",2)]

Comment: @PHA: but those don't have the same first item.

Comment: Aha, now that you've edited your question it makes more sense. You want all pairs whose first element is also the first element of at least one other pair?

Comment: @gspr I tried to explain better the question. I actually need to find all tuples that with the first item appeared more than once

Comment: Downvote and vote for close retracted in light of the new information.

Comment: @gspr updated the question title as well!

Answer (score 5):

You can first group the tuples by their first element and then concat those groups which have at least two elements. This solution is not O(n^2) but imposes an `Ord` constraint.

```
import Data.List (groupBy, sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

someFilter :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
someFilter = concat
           . filter ((>= 2) . length)
           . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
           . sortBy (comparing fst)
```

Comment: I'd prefer `not . null . drop 2` to `(>= 2) . length` since the latter visits all the list while the former does not go deeper than the 3rd element. (Not that it really matters here -- the original is arguably more readable)

Comment: @chi, for list fusion purposes (not relevant here), it's better to go with something like `atLeastLength n xs = foldr go (==0) xs n where {go _ _ 0 = True; go _ c k = c (k-1)}`, which unfortunately is the least clear of all.

Answer (score 0):

As other answer, already said, you need to group your lists. The obvious candidate is as in Frerich solution to use `Data.List.groupBy`, however, I often find creating a map is easier (you don't need to sort).

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

someFilter xs = M.keys $ M.filter (>=1) 
                                  (M.fromList (+) [(x,1) | (x,_) <- xs])
```